# Como obtener y guardar el valor de un listado en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de seleccionar vario valores de un `<select>`

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Ejemplo: al escoger Volvo necesito que se guarde el valor en un objeto y me lo muestre el valor para saber que opcion elegi, despues seleccionar en el listado Audi y que se guarde de nuevo la informacion en el mismo objeto donde se encuentra el valor de Volvo y que el objeto me muestre Volvo y Audi y continuar de esa manera hasta que ya no nesesite escoger otro valor del listado.

Ejemplo de como se mostraria en la pantalla los valores seleccionados en el listado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Esto es posible con el objeto `<select>`?

Comment: te refieres a seleccionar varios al mismo tiempo , para luego enviarlos?

Comment: Si, sopongamos que selecciono 5 valores del listado y quiero guardarlos en un objeto, que se muestren los valores seleccionados para que el usuario los pueda ver y esa cadena de valores la voy a usar en mi bdd como una con condicion para filtrar registros

Comment: mira este [LINK](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox) para ver si te ayuda, se llama selct2 es una libreria de jquery, ya que por html por si solo , no he encontrado.

Comment: y lo otro para poder enviar varios datos pero sin librerias es que uses el ejemplo que te dieron como respuesta y apretando ctrl+click para ir seleccionado multilples items.

Comment: Perfecto, el que necesito es Multi-select boxes (pillbox)

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que buscas en un select multiple:

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tratas de hacer es un multiselect, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

Añadir el atributo `multiple` dentro de la etiqueta `<select>`

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Para obtener los valores seleccionados podemos usar Jquery:

```js
$("#multiple").change(function() {
  var data = $(this).val();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="multiple" multiple>
  <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Realicé el siguiente código donde se van guardando los valores en un objeto y se imprimen los valores en el `console.log` las opciones que se han estado seleccionando:

```js
var cars = [];

$('#carVal').on('change', function(){
  var val = $('#carVal option:selected').val();
  cars.push(val);
  console.log(cars);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="carVal" multiple>
  <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Espero te ayude.